# Is it possible to see extreme votes for specific tags?

Tags: support, feature-request

If you've got more than 10,000 reputation points you can study "Questions with extreme votes", "Answers with extreme votes" and so on under Review Queues > Tools. You can even subset by period like "Today", "2d" and "30d". But is it in any way possible to view the same information for specific tags like [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) or [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)?

If not, could this be a feature to be considered in the future?

Comment: You can use the advanced search features to do the same: https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching

Comment: Can search for extreme votes by tag like this https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5Bjavascript%5D+is%3Aq%20created%3A30d..&mixed=0

Comment: Thanks for the feedback everyone! But if this functionality is usefull for *all* questions under `Tools`, shouldn't it be at least as useful for specific tags? And much more accessible by just including it under tools rather than using advanced searches?

Comment: E.g. all answers to Python questions in the last 7 days with a score of -2 or lower is [`[python] is:a created:7d.. score:..-2`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5Bpython%5D+is%3Aa+created%3A7d..+score%3A..-2). That link sorts by votes.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thank you! I'll be sure to use that instead. Is it possible to do this for each available category under `Tools` like "Recently protected" for example? For *some* of the categories besides votes (like "Views") I know you can specify range with `views:500-1000` though.

Comment: I haven’t checked but I suspect protected questions can be located via “hasnotice”. Take I to account that even on SO there are not *that* many such posts as to make splitting out per tag interesting or useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [advanced search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) options:

`is:a` will show only answers

`created:xd` will show only posts within the last `x` days

`score:x..` will show only posts above `x` score

Comment: I am not 100% sure but afaik `created:xd` shows only posts posted exactly `x` days before. I think you might have written `created:..xd`.